# How to access Config related keys when a module name is specified

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When looking at the config files in phoenix, if I create a config like this:

```
config :myapp,
  http: 4000
```

I can reference that key in my code like this:

```
Application.fetch_env!(:myapp, :http)
```

Sometimes the config seems to be specific to a module, like the below has MyApp.Endpoint.

Is this just breaking up the config into sections kind of?  How do I reference the http port like below in my code if I need too?

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sometimes the config seems to be specific to a module, like the below
>   has MyApp.Endpoint.
>
> Is this just breaking up the config into sections kind of?

tldr;

Yes.  With your config file, you create something like this:

```
[
  {:ecto_repos, [MyApp.Repo]},
  {.Repo,
   [
     username: "postgres",
     password: "postgres",
     database: "myapp_dev",
     hostname: "localhost",
     pool_size: 10
   ]},

  {:http, [port: 4000]},   <===**** HERE ****
  {:included_applications, []},

  {MyAppWeb.Endpoint,     <====**** HERE ****
   [
     url: [host: "localhost"],
     secret_key_base: "rchq5yMDPqqEBzFR+wIoqpc+kNquiyNDYUp/K8aF2Yj6POl/gjfj0H0rljE06LI5",
     render_errors: [view: MyAppWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ["html", "json"]],
     pubsub: [name: Rum.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2],
     http: [port: 4000],
     debug_errors: true,
     code_reloader: true,
     check_origin: false,
     watchers: [
       node: [
         "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
         "--mode",
         "development",
         "--watch-stdin",
         {:cd, "/Users/7stud/phoenix_apps/book/myapp/assets"}
       ]
     ],
     live_reload: [
       patterns: [~r/priv\/static\/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        ~r/priv\/gettext\/.*(po)$/, ~r/lib\/myapp_web\/views\/.*(ex)$/,
        ~r/lib\/myapp_web\/templates\/.*(eex)$/]
     ]
   ]},
```

> How do I
>   reference the http port like below in my code if I need too?
>
> ```
> config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint,
>   http: [port: 4000],
>   debug_errors: true
> ```

If you look at that config section and remove the newlines, you get:

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint, http: [port: 4000], debug_errors: true
```

And, if you add in some parentheses, you get:

```
config(:myapp, MyApp.Endpoint, http: [port: 4000], debug_errors: true)
```

That is a function call where the first argument is `:myapp`, the second argument is `MyApp.Endpoint`, and then this part:

```
http: [port: 4000], debug_errors: true
```

is a `Keyword list`.  Digressing for a moment...in elixir, you can define functions like this:

```
  def go(x, y, z) do
    IO.puts x
    IO.puts y
    IO.inspect z
  end
```

and call them like this:

```
My.go(10, 20, a: 1, b: 2)
```

which will output:

```
10
20
[a: 1, b: 2]
```

That demonstrates that if the last arguments in a function call have a particular syntax, then the last arguments will all be gathered into something called a `Keyword list` and passed to the function as one argument.  So, even though it looks like you are calling `My.go()` with four arguments, you are really calling it with three arguments.

As a result, this function call:

```
config(:myapp, MyApp.Endpoint, http: [port: 4000], debug_errors: true)
```

is calling a `config/3` function definition.

How come you can call a `config/3` function when no such function is defined in the config file?  This line:

```
use Mix.Config
```

injects the `config/3` function definition into the file.  That is a problem with elixir: there is a lot of magic stuff that happens, which makes it hard to figure out where function definitions come from.

At this point, you know that a `config/3` function is being called in the config file:

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true
```

Additionally, the line `use Mix.Config` at the top of the config file is a hint that `config/3` might be defined in that module, so you can go peruse the [Mix.Config docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Config.html#config/3).  Sure enough, there is a `config/3` function that is described in the docs.  There's also a `config/2` function described in the docs, which is called here:

```
config :myapp,
  http: 4000
```

If you read the docs for `config/2` it seems pretty easy to understand how things work: when you set keys and values with `config/2`, you can retrieve a particular value associated with a key by calling:

```
Application.get_env(:myapp, key)
```

For instance,

```
Application.get_env(:myapp, :http)
#=> 4000
```

However, when you set keys and values with `config/3`, you cannot retrieve a particular value associated with a key--instead you end up retrieving a whole list of key/value pairs:

```
keyword_list = Application.get_env(:myapp, module)
```

`config/3` creates a nested structure where the module is the key and its value is a Keyword list made up of the key/value pairs you specify in the config file, e.g.:

```
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true
```

Another way of getting your head around that is by thinking of a nested map:

```
%{
  myapp: %{
    http: 4000,  #<== config/2
    my_app_endpoint: %{http: [port: 4000, debug_errors: true]}  #<== config/3
  }
```

...and `Application.get_env()` only allows you to specify two keys, such as:

```
Application.get_env(:myapp, :http)  #=> 4000
```

or:

```
Application.get_env(:myapp, :my_app_endpoint)  #=> %{http: [port: 4000, debug_errors: true]}
```

Once you retrieve the keyword_list:

```
keyword_list = Application.get_env(:myapp, module)
```

then you have to use your general knowledge of elixir to retrieve a value associated with a particular key from the keyword list:

```
all = Application.get_all_env(:myapp)
IO.inspect all  #=> lots of stuff (which is not a keyword list)

keyword_list = Application.get_env(:myapp, MyApp.Endpoint)
IO.inspect keyword_list #=> a keyword list with lots of key/value pairs 
http = Keyword.get(keyword_list, :http)
IO.inspect http  #=> [port: 4000]
port = Keyword.get(http_keyword_list, :port)
IO.inspect port  #=>4000
```

Answer (score 6):

What you get back in this case from your `fetch_env!/2` call is a [keyword list](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html). You can either access it the way you'd do with a Map:

```
Application.fetch_env!(:myapp, :http)[:port]
```

OR convert it to a Map, and do it that way:

```
Application.fetch_env!(:myapp, :http) |> Map.new |> Map.get(:port)
```

EDIT - based on @BrettBeatty's comment

You can use the `Keyword.get/2` function as well:

```
:myapp |> Application.get_env(:http) |> Keyword.get(:port)
```

Comment: So you don't have to say you want the config for the module  MyApp.Endpoint anywhere?  Confused as to why some config's have a module name ( MyApp.Endpoint) after the name (myapp).

Comment: That's up to whoever is consuming the config. It's just another level of namespacing, so the example you gave suggests :http and :debug_errors belong to endpoint instead of configuring your app as a whole.

Comment: I personally like using `Keyword.get/2`. It ends up looking like `:myapp |> Application.get_env(:http) |> Keyword.get(:port)`.

Comment: @BrettBeatty the Keyword get works just as well, I prefer Maps myself.